# How to work around the lack of invariant/contravariant type parameters in Dart?

Tags: dart, generics, covariance, contravariance, generic-variance

Dart unfortunately lacks ([by design](https://dart.dev/faq#q-why-are-generics-covariant)) the ability to specify invariant or contravariant type parameters. So when I need them, how do I work around their absence?

Take the abstract setting of a `Producer<T>` and a `Consumer<T>` class.

```dart
abstract class Producer<T> {
  T produce();
}

abstract class Consumer<T> {
  void consume(T item);
}
```

The type parameter in `Producer` should be covariant, but in `Consumer` it should be contravariant (a concrete example: method parameters are contravariant, return types are covariant). However, Dart will automatically make the type parameter in `Consumer` covariant, without a way of specifying otherwise.

So if some other code component needs, for example, a `Consumer<num>`, conceptually it should accept a `Consumer<Object>`, because if a consumer accepts any object, it will certainly accept an number. But if I just write:

```dart
void someFunction(Consumer<num> consumer);
```

This will accept only `Consumer<num>` or `Consumer<int>`, `Consumer<float>` etc. which will cause errors.

So how should I write it instead?
Some options that occurred to me:

```dart
void someFunction(Consumer<dynamic> consumer);
```

This removes static type checking, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround, generics are currently covariant.
The best you can do is either:

- Wait for variance annotations (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/524), or
- Let "consumer" be a function instead of a class.

If the only thing the `Consumer` class does is to `consume`, it's a [single-method interface](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-one-member-abstract-class-when-a-simple-function-will-do), and you can just use a function type, and pass around function values, instead.

Comment: Unfortunately my actual use case is more than a single method... I guess I'll have to forego static checking in some way or another for this scenario.